# Oracle Drop Table with YYYMMDD and YYYMMDD_HHMMSS

Tags: oracle

I have some tables end with date (YYYYMMDD), some end with HHMMSS:

```
INVENLEVEL_20160419
INVENLEVEL_20160419_120232     <-optional to exist
INVENLEVEL_20160425 
INVENLEVEL_20160426
INVENLEVEL_20160426_032112     <-optional to exist
```

I need to keep tables within 7 days and drop other INVENLEVEL TABLES.

Expected Results, the following 2 tables deleted:

```
INVENLEVEL_20160419
INVENLEVEL_20160419_120232
```

Im able to drop for tables with date, but not the one with HHMMSS.

```
FOR x IN ( SELECT TABLE_NAME
                    FROM USER_TABLES
                    WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(TABLE_NAME, 'INVENLEVEL_[[:digit:]]{8}')
                    AND TO_DATE(SUBSTR(TABLE_NAME, -8), 'yyyymmdd') <= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 7
                   ) LOOP

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE ' ||
    x.TABLE_NAME ||
    ' PURGE';
```

How can i also drop for the table with HHMMSS also? Please note that tables with HHMMSS is optional to exist, means, sometimes we have it, sometime not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this, perhaps:

```
with sample_data as (select 'INVENLEVEL_20160419' table_name from dual union all
                     select 'INVENLEVEL_20160419_120232' table_name from dual union all
                     select 'INVENLEVEL_20160425' table_name from dual union all
                     select 'INVENLEVEL_20160426' table_name from dual union all
                     select 'INVENLEVEL_20160426_032112' table_name from dual union all
                     select 'NEW_20160426_032112' table_name from dual union all
                     select 'FRED' table_name from dual)
---- end of mimicking your data; see SQL below
select table_name,
       to_date(substr(table_name, 12, 8), 'yyyymmdd') dt
from   sample_data
where  REGEXP_LIKE(TABLE_NAME, '^INVENLEVEL_[[:digit:]]{8}($|_[[:digit:]]{6})')
and    to_date(substr(table_name, 12, 8), 'yyyymmdd') <= trunc(sysdate -7);

TABLE_NAME                 DT       
-------------------------- ----------
INVENLEVEL_20160419        19/04/2016
INVENLEVEL_20160419_120232 19/04/2016
```

Obviously, you wouldn't need the sample_data subquery - I just used that in order to have data for the SQL to work against. You'd query your user_tables instead.

I amended your regexp to additionally check that it had either reached the end of the string after the 8 digits or there was another underscore followed by 6 digits.

Then I amended your substr to check for the 8 characters from the 12th position, in order to get the date - you have to do it like this, since if you use the end of the string as you had been doing, the date is not necessarily 8 characters from the end.